# Corrupted IDA database .i64 file (Empty Header)

Tags: ida

Im my 10 years using IDA Pro this never happend.

I saved using IDA Pro 7.7 when I go to open today
I find out that IDA PRO didnt put header on file

If I try to open says "**File .... is not an IDA database**" for obvious reasons.

If I edit the header and add first 15 bytes from other database
"49 44 41 32 00 00 FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05" IDA opens the file and starts unpacking but  then I get error "**bTree error: bad B-tree header**"

Its possible to recover or rebuild the header?

2 Images to explain what is missing on the IDA database file
[image: Curupted .i64]

[image: Other Normal .i64 no related]

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. This is clearly something to report to Hex-Rays. They may even be able to help restoring it. Current version is 8.1.221006, though. And you probably need an active maintenance to get their attention.